# Can't enter text on ui-select in angularjs 1.5.8

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I have one ui-select as the following:

```
<ui-select multiple  ng-disabled="!report.scenario" ng-model="report.students">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="">{{$item.id}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="{id: student.id} as student in CMP_PASSENGER_MASTER | filter: $select.search" refresh="refreshPassengers($select.search)" refresh-delay="300" reset-search-input="false">
        <div>{{student.fullName}}</div>
        <small>ID: {{student.id}}</small>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

The problem that I have is that I can't enter any text on the input which maps to this ui-select. Only works if I paste text (*Right Click -> Paste*) CTRL+V, doesn't work either, though. It's like at some point in the ui-select directive is preventing the key down event.

These are my bower dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.8",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.4.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "angular-ui-select": "^0.19.4",
    "angular-bootstrap": "^2.2.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-switch": "^0.5.1",
    "angular-ui-switch": "^0.1.1",
    "angular-xeditable": "^0.4.0",
    "angularUtils-pagination": "angular-utils-pagination#^0.11.1",
    "angular-confirm-modal": "^1.2.6"
  },
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug on the version of the ui-select 0.9.4, which I was using. For more details, you can read it here:  github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/commit/0d81493

I downgraded the version to 0.9.3 it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just seeing one thing that I cannot explain and that is the `reset-search-input` this should not be on the `ui-select-choices` but on the ui-select tap. As this will reset after selecting a option. Try and change that and see if it helps. [ui-select Wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select)

Comment: Hi, yeah you're right. I moved to the ui-select, but it is still not working.

Comment: Can you share a plunker? Also did you try version 19.5?

Comment: In plunkers I cannot reproduce it. This is the bug: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/commit/0d81493